# $\textrm{Aut}(C^n)$ automorphism of complex number $C^n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I want to prove following automorphism
\begin{align}
  \textrm{Aut} (\mathbf{C}^n) \simeq \textrm{GL}(n, \mathbf{C})\ltimes \mathbf{C}^n = \{ z \mapsto Az +v | A \in \textrm{GL}(n, \mathbf{C}), v\in \mathbf{C}^n \}
\end{align}

Can anybody gives me some hint or proper references?

---

I think it is related with [note](https://math.unibas.ch/uploads/x4epersdb/files/Chap2_01.pdf), example 1.4 
which states an automorphism $\psi$ of $C^n$ is called affine trasnformation if it is of the form 
\begin{align}
\psi(x) = Ax +b, \quad \textrm{where} \quad A\in GL_n, \quad b\in C^n
\end{align}

---

Comment: Automorphisms as what sort of object?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft, i think it is biholomorphism

Comment: You think? But you are the one asking, so there is nobody else who could possibly know.

Comment: I do not think it is biholomorphism! I think you mean as an affine space. In that case it is in fact true, although I would need some time to come up with a proof

Comment: The same question over the real numbers is easier to visualize. There you can kind of understand what the maps $x \mapsto Ax + v$ do geometrically and also see that the subset O(n) semidirect R^n is the set of rigid motions, a very natural geometric concept in real Euclidean space. If you were somehow thinking about this and trying to generalize to complex numbers then biholomorphic is much to general!

Answer (score 4):

This is blatantly not true (assuming you are looking for biholomorphisms). There are many many other automorphisms of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

For example,
$$
(z,w) \mapsto (z,w+f(z))
$$
is an automorphism of $\mathbb{C}^2$ for *every* choice of holomorphic $f$.

In fact, the automorphism group of $\mathbb{C}^n$ is "too large" to even be a Lie group.

Comment: A reference to what? It is straight-forward to check that the mapping above is biholomorphic: if $$(z,w+f(z)) = (z',w'+f(z')),$$ then $z=z'$ and consequently, $w=w'$. You can easily work out the inverse map.